# How does C interpret int in pointers and why it differ from char pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int *c=12345;
  printf("dec:%d  hex:%x", c ,&c); // (1)
 }
```

The line (1) prints

```
dec:12345  hex:8af123
```

where `8af123` is obviously the address which is random and machine dependent.

When I put in

```
printf("dec:%d", *c); // (1)
```

it fails, obviously.

So my question is as per theoretical concept:

- **`*c` should holds the value `12345` but it is not. why?**

And in this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>  
void main()  
{  
  char *c='a';  
  printf("address store in c:%d  value point by c:%c address of c:%x", c,*c ,&c); //Focus line  
}
```

Output is:

```
adderess store in c:9105699 value point by c:a address of c:8af564
```

- **why it is storing 'a' in `*c` instead in `c`?**

I am using gcc compiler 4.4.3.

Comment: What's `str`? Do you mean `c`?

Comment: What's `str` here ? I dont see any such declaration here for that .Related to `C` may be ?

Comment: `int *c=12345;` can't be done, you haven't allocated memory for the pointer `c`

Comment: You're defining a pointer c with value memory offset 12345. Did you want a non-pointer variable that contains integer 12345? Try compiling with the `-Wformat` flag and GCC will warn you that you're passing the wrong type to printf.

Comment: @Math That would set the address `c` points to (but needs a cast).

Comment: @DanielFischer I think he thinks that doing that command he will add the value 12345 to some memory location, once nobody knows what exactly memory address has to be allocated. But first he has to allocate the memory, and then assign a value to it.

Comment: @Math `int *c=12345;` is declaring 'my pointer is pointing to address 12345' not that it contains 12345 (that would require dereferencing the pointer and writing to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is as per theoretical concept `*str` hold the value `12345` but it is not. why?

```
int *c=12345;
```

is the same as:

```
int *c;
c=12345;
```

It is **not** the same as:

```
int *c;
*c=12345;
```

There is a semantical quirk in the C language here. The  `*` belongs to the declaration, yet it only applies to that specific variable.

You could clarify the fact that `*` belongs to the declaration by putting it next to the data type:

```
int* c = 12345;  // Don't format your declaration like this,
                 // see next example as to why
```

If you do, you will run into trouble when declaring multiple variables in the same statement:

```
int* a, b, c; // a is a pointer to int, b and c are plain int

// it is the same as:
int *a; int b; int c;

// and **not**
int *a; int *b; int *c;
```

So, you just have to learn that the `*` belongs to the declaration. There are no problems caused by this, because you cannot safely assign `*c` unless you first have assigned a valid address to `c`.

> why it is storing 'a' in *c instead in c?

```
  char *c='a';  
  printf("%d  %c %x", c,*c ,&c); //Focus line
```

You are declaring a pointer to char that points to memory location 97 (The ascii value of `a` is 97).
You then try to print the pointer as a number (should print `97`, but see below), the value of memory location 97 as a character (`c` is an invalid pointer at this stage, so the result is undefined, and the address of the pointer `c` (`c` is an aout variable located on the stack).

When I compile this code I get a 
Warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
when assigning `97` to the character pointer `c`.
When I run this code in cygwin I get a Segmentation fault from the undefined behaviour.

Comment: This seems more closer to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
int *c=12345;
```

You just made a pointer that points to the (probably) invalid address `12345`.

If you pass `c` (no `*`) to `printf`, you're passing the pointer itself.  Therefore, `printf` simply sees the number `12345`, and prints that.  It has no way of knowing that that's supposed to be a pointer.

If you pass `*c`, to `printf`, you're *dereferencing* the pointer – you're passing the value at memory address `12345`.
Since that's not a valid address, the dereference operation will crash (to be precise, will behave undefinededly) before it ever gets to `printf`.

Comment: Moreover it's a constraint violation, which the compiler will diagnose. OP should not be ignoring this message. You cannot initialize pointers with integers (except the integer constant expression 0, which is a null pointer constant).

Comment: I'd say the constraint violation is a separate issue (orthogonal to main "using a dodgy address" problem). For example, I'm not sure that `int *c = (int *)12345;` would help much even though the type cast solves the constraint violation.